# Implementing Navigation Drawer Without TitleBar

Tags: android, button, navigation, drawer

I'm planning to implement a navigation bar to let users navigate to different activites.
But here's the problem,
I've found plenty articles about creating a navigation drawer but it seems doesn't work for me , because my UI doesn't have any titlebar.
And what i actually want is to call up the navigation drawer whenever users press on a button near to the navigation drawer.

Is there any possible way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple.

Here is your main activity's layout, `activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_list_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here's your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navi_1:
                        // on 1st item in the menu, do something
                        break;
                    case R.id.navi_2:
                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do something
                        break;
                }
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return false;
            }
        });

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    // [...]

    private void openDrawer() {
        if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView);
        }
    }

    private void closeDrawer() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can open the drawer with `openDrawer()` and close it with `closeDrawer()`.

A sample `navigation.xml` file which is located under the *menu* dir in the *res* (resources) folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navi_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:title="First item"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navi_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:title="Second item"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Sample `drawer_list_header.xml` file, located under the *layout* dir in the *res* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/list_header_final">

</ImageView>
```

Here are some notes:

- You have to declare a menu file for the drawer, see `app:menu="@menu/navigation"` in the layout file.
- You might want to declare a header layout, which is displayed over the menu elements in the drawer, see `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_list_header"`.
- The drawer can be opened by a fling-like action from the edge of the screen. To prevent the users from doing that, you might want to lock/unlock your drawer on action using `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(...);`, see the [documentation for details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode%28int%29).

Also note that in order to use NavigationView, you'll need the latest design support lib by adding the dependency to your module's gradle file: `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`.
See more about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: But my main_activity is already in relative layout , can i just add in the v4 widget code?

Comment: The DrawerLayout must be the root, but you can replace the FrameLayout in my code with your existing RelativeLayout, it's gonna have the same look-and-feel but you'll have access to the drawer.

Comment: It's available in the support design lib, see [this post's very end](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) about it.
Basically you have to add a dependency to your gradle file:
`compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks , may i know what is the latest version of com.android.design dependency library ?

Comment: Because it shows "this support library should not use a lower version(22)"

Comment: I think it's 22.2.0 as you can see here: `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`. You might have to download the latest Android Support Library (v23) in your SDK Manager.

The *""this support library should not use a lower version(22)"* text is just a warning which shows that there is a newer version available. Press ALT + ENTER and select to update it, the Android Studio will probably change the numbers to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for this , one more question , the menu items and list should be declare in main_menu.xml or create one xml under layout? because the code shows app:header=@layout

Comment: The header is a custom layout file. I recommend using a simple ImageView as root for that if you want to display only an image. The menu file contains the menu items, thus it is placed in the menu dir. Refer to [this post's NavigationView part](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) if you want to know more.

Comment: I Don't really get what you mean , how can i fix this ?

Comment: Oops, as well as the menu/navigation . Sorry i'm new to android development.

Comment: The list you are displaying in the drawer goes into a single  drawer_menu.xml file (this is just a sample name, you can name it whatever you want) which will be located under the menu dir. Then you change `app:menu="@menu/navigation"` to `app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"`. This drawer_menu.xml contains the menu elements, which is NOT a layout file but a simple menu descriptor. I added a sample code to the answer (**note** that I called it navigation.xml this time, not drawer_menu.xml).

Comment: Oh , i got it ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Can i ask one more question? how can i open up the drawer from the right ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155127/navigation-drawer-starts-from-right-side (My question)

Comment: I posted my answer there. You have to change the layout_gravity attribute of NavigationView to a more appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement `DrawerLayout` with out `ActionBar`. You can manually open and close the `DrawerLayout` like

```
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```