# Navigation drawer starts from right side

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can i make the navigation drawer open from the right to the left?

Main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    android:background="#FFE7FF"/>
```

drawer_header.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

navigation.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/homelogo"
        android:title="Home" /></group></menu>
```

This is how i create it in main activity

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
              (..........)
```

How can i make it ? I've tried android:gravity but it doesn't work.

Comment: btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hideKeyboard();
    handleDrawerLayout();

   }
  });

Comment: this is duplicate question please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852091/how-can-i-open-navigation-drawer-from-right-side-to-left

Comment: i've tried , but i'm opening the drawer using navigation view ,  drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView); , so i can't use gravity right inside this line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main.xml` there is the `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` which has the following attribute: `android:layout_gravity="end"`. You have to set it to *right*, so it will be like this: `android:layout_gravity="right"`.
The rest is done by the design support lib.

*Note that the Android Studio will show a warning that you should use `end` instead of `right` in order to ensure correct behavior in right-to-left languages. You can ignore this message.*

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change anything , btw i've decided to change it to the left. Thank you so much.

Comment: Simply create a totally blank application, with one navigation drawer activity in it (just defaults of Android Studio) and follow your simple step to change gravity to right. You'll end of with `No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Try setting *android:layout_gravity="end"* instead of  *android:layout_gravity="start"***

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me, adding end to the layout_gravity

Answer (score 0):

it does change , only two things to do ,

After addig a new activity to your android app from android studio->file->new->activity ->Navigation Draw....

you have to change 
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
in main layout's 
    android.support.design.widget.NavigationView  and 
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END); 
in your OnNavigationItemSelected() function in main activity .

Comment: It doesn't work. You didn't tested your answer. @omkar Dusane