# How to load the drawer as in the image on a button click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, sidebar, drawer

I have an app that displays the default activity as:

[image: default_activity]

When clicked the hamburger icon opens left main navigation drawer as:

[image: navigation_drawer]

And when clicked the FILTER button opens another drawer from the right as:

[image: filter]

I know how the left navigation drawer is displayed (all java codes and layouts)

What is the code for displaying the drawer that is opening from the right ?

and also i wanna know, how the on click listener is set up even if the FILTER button is outside the toolbar ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can achieve this using a navigation drawer https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: create custom layout for side bar and load it into navigation drawer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer (Google+ vs. YouTube)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/navigation-drawer-google-vs-youtube)

Comment: check out my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451594/slidingpanellayout-not-work-well-from-right-to-left-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of `tools:openDrawer` to end (**i.e** `tools:openDrawer="end"`), also add `android:layout_gravity="end"` in `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>`. Here's the solution.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //Add this piece of code
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }else{
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then just click on the (✓check) mark.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this  -http://updateunlimited.blogspot.in/2015/12/double-sided-nav-drawers.html

it will take less time 
also check how it open from right -https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358114/4741746  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155976/4741746  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156831/4741746

Best of luck